# How to save a MethodInfo pointer and later call that function?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, methodinfo

C#/CIL/Reflection.Emit question:

I'm trying to define a type that has a function pointer, instantiate that type, create a static method on another type (because I don't know how else to make "just a function"), give a pointer to this static method to the instance, and later use that pointer to call the function.

I've had little success. :-(

Here's the type:

```
Thunk = modb.DefineType("Thunk");

Thunk.DefineField("Env" , Env.AsType(), FieldAttributes.Public);
Thunk.DefineField("Expr", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public); // int is the correct type according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldftn.aspx

Thunk.CreateType();
```

So far so good (I think). Then I create one of these guys and assign the function pointer:

```
var methodBuilder = MainType.DefineMethod("my_other_little_function", MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(Int64), new[] {Env.AsType()});
{
    var il2 = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    il2.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il2.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    binding.Expr.Compile(il2);
    il2.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ThunkCtor);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, Thunk.GetField("Env"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, methodBuilder);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, Thunk.GetField("Expr"));
```

As far as I can tell, this part is working just fine. The problem is elsewhere, when I try to call it:

```
var func = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, Thunk.GetField("Expr"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, func);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, Thunk.GetField("Env"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, func);

il.EmitCalli(OpCodes.Calli, CallingConventions.Standard, typeof(Int64), new[] { Env.AsType() }, null);
```

If I try to run the program created by this, I get at error before any of the bytecode is executed (or at least that's how it appears):

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
```

If instead I replace the EmitCalli() with code to simply pop the function pointer and the argument and push a number, the rest of the program works fine. So how am I supposed to call this function?

Thanks so much. :-)

Comment: I would think that il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, func) should be il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, func.LocalIndex). Same should be done for Stloc

Comment: I think that part is ok, as I'm using it elsewhere. And this seems to suggest that it's fine: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc.aspx

Comment: Why are you trying to use function pointers instead of delegates?

Comment: Also, have you tried running peverify on the generated assembly?

Comment: No, I didn't know about peverify, thanks! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @svick Because I don't know how to use delegates to do this. I can define a method, generate the IL for it, create a delegate for it with CreateDelegate()... but then what? How do I push this delegate to the stack? And once it's there, how do I call it?

Comment: After looking at your question in more detail, I don't understand what exactly do you want. Could you include a short, but complete sample code that shows your problem. And ideally also include the code you want to generate in C#. Also, there might be some error unrelated to the method pointer in your code, for example, you're using a local variable in `il2`, but I don't see you declaring it.

Comment: There were other errors which peverify showed me, and now I am able to get the Ldftn/Calli to work, though peverify now says "Instruction cannot be verified." I am writing a compiler, and what I am doing right now is trying to figure out how to have first-class functions. I though having an object that holds a function pointer would work, but as far as I can tell, Calli is just going to give me that error, and there's no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you like solving problems like this just for the fun of it, another option is to use a library to generate the desired IL.

[Fasterflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) is a library with lots of reflection helpers. For instance, to get a delegate for a method, just write:

```
var delegate = typeof(YourClass).DelegateForCallStaticMethod( "MyStaticMethod" );
delegate( args );
```

The library uses DynamicMethod and IL generation behind the scenes, and also has extensions that do not require you to declare and use a variable for the delegate (although that will be much faster if you intend to call it repeatedly, e.g. in a tight loop). The simple variant looks like this:

```
var result = typeof(YourClass).CallStaticMethod( "MyStaticMethod", args );
```

Fasterflect caches generated delegates (as it's quite expensive to compile the generated IL), so the added performance cost for each invocation in the simple scenario equates to the cost of doing the cache lookup.

Disclaimer: I'm involved in said project. That said, writing IL by hand really is no fun task. Another good option for IL generation is the Mono.Cecil library, although I'm not familiar with the particulars of what it offers.

Comment: Intrigued. Does `DelegateForCallStaticMethod` return `dynamic`, to allow invoking the instance?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IntPtr` for function pointers instead of `int`. CLR documentation sometimes called this type "native int".